# Paint a line step to step with time function

Tags: javascript

I wrote this code but it don't work. Javascript draws the line at once, instead of showing me how the line is drawn

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var i = 200;

  while (i<220) {
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 10;
  ctx.lineCap = "butt";
  ctx.moveTo(20, 20);
  ctx.lineTo(i, 20);
  ctx.stroke();  

  console.log("Hello");
  sleep(200);
  console.log("World!");

  i++

}  

function sleep(milliseconds) {
  const date = Date.now();
  let currentDate = null;
  do {
    currentDate = Date.now();
  } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
}
```

```html
<p>The three different line caps:</p>
<canvas id="myCanvas">Example</canvas>
```

Comment: use setTimeout or setInterval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `setInterval` to see the animation like this :

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
let i = 0;
const startInterval = function(){
i += 5
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.lineCap = "butt";
ctx.moveTo(20, 20);
ctx.lineTo(i, 20);
ctx.stroke();  
if(i === 220){
  clearInterval(interval);
  console.log("finished")
  }
}

let interval = setInterval(startInterval, 200)
```

```html
    <p>The three different line caps:</p>
    <canvas id="myCanvas">
    Example</canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain exactly why that behaviour is occurring, but I do have a solution. Typically if you want to perform the same task in repeated intervals, you use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval). There's also [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) which you could use, but the first is more appropriate.

```js
var number = 0;

// you pass the function to call, and how often as arguments
let count = setInterval(countUpTo5, 500);

function countUpTo5() {
    if (number > 5) {
        // by passing the name of the interval, you can stop it
        clearInterval(count);
    } else {
        console.log(number);
        number++;
    }
}
```

Good luck, and if you'd like more help just leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

That's because canvas does not update itself while code is running. You can easily see the effect by changing canvas border color for example. The only way to solve this is to imulate async operations with setTimeout or setInterval, as offered above. By this you make the stack empty for a while and canvas repaints as the result within each iteration.